# Pymongoarrow - Pandas Dataframe to Mongodb Document

Tags: pandas, mongodb

Picture of the error

[image: 1]

What should I do?

this is the code:

```
import pymongoarrow
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pprint

MONGODB_URI = '...'
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
db = client.blog
collection = db.posts

from pymongoarrow.monkey import patch_all
patch_all()

from pymongoarrow.api import Schema
schema = Schema({'_id': ObjectId, 'age': int, 'name': str})

df = collection.find_pandas_all({}, schema = schema)
df

from pymongoarrow.api import write
write(db.new, df)
```

I think it has something to do with the datatype (_id):

picture of the dataframe

[image: 2]

I tried doing it with a simple dataset and it went on without a hitch. So I think it has something to do with the ObjectId.

[image: code executed correctly]